# Deploy service dynamically according to load with Googl Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently working on an application deployed with Google Kubernetes Engine. I want to be able to change the behavior of a service if the load on my application reaches a certain point. The idea is to deploy a similar service which consumes less ressources so that my application can still work with a bigger load.

Is it possible with Google Kubernetes Engine ?

Comment: Please describe what the 'change of behavior' - as it's rather vague and could mean anything.

Comment: The goal here is, when experiencing too much load, to switch between a more sophisticated service to a simpler one. So simply, at a certain load, run a deployment in order to replace another service.

Comment: I guess it is feasible to approach via [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) with the custom metric that can auto scale your target app pod based on the metric defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done with HPA and custom metrics in prometheus. We are using this setup to autoscale our deployments based on requests per minute.

Prometheus scrapes this metric from the application and prometheus adapter makes them available to kubernetes.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter